# Add a fixed value to a range of cells using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, assign

I am trying to fill a value in a selected range based on the value of the cell directly to a cell's left.

In any given range there will be a set of valid dates. I would like to select a blank cell to the right of the dates and then the macro should display the Financial year and Quarter.

e.g.
A1 = "20/12/2022", A2 = "15/08/2023"
Should give:
B1 = "2022-23 Q3", B2 = "2023-24 Q2"

When I select cell B1 and use:

```vb
ActiveCell.Value = "=IF(MONTH(RC[-1])<4,YEAR(RC[-1])-1&""-""&RIGHT(YEAR(RC[-1]),2)&"" Q4"",IF(MONTH(RC[-1])<7,YEAR(RC[-1])&""-""&RIGHT(YEAR(RC[-1]),2)+1&"" Q1"",IF(MONTH(RC[-1])<10,YEAR(RC[-1])&""-""&RIGHT(YEAR(RC[-1]),2)+1&"" Q2"",IF(MONTH(RC[-1])<13,YEAR(RC[-1])&""-""&RIGHT(YEAR(RC[-1]),2)+1&"" Q3""))))"
```

It assigns the correct solution to the active cell.

Issue 1: If I select cells B1:B5 I would like the macro to assign the same formula to those cells.

Whatever I try just populates the first cell.

I know that I can then double click on the bottom right corner of the cell and it will populate but I would like to achieve it in one click not two.

Issue 2: Getting the macro to work if, say I highlighted cells H7:H20 (with the data being in G7:G20) so basically I could click any range on the spreadsheet and it will populate that range, based on the value of the cells directly to its left.

The end result works for a single cell and puts a formula in the cell, with the cell displaying the correct text, but if the result was just the plain text instead that would be fine.

---

I found a solution:

```vb
Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In Selection
    rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "=IF(MONTH(RC[-1])<4,YEAR(RC[-1])-1&""-""&RIGHT(YEAR(RC[-1]),2)&"" Q4"",IF(MONTH(RC[-1])<7,YEAR(RC[-1])&""-""&RIGHT(YEAR(RC[-1]),2)+1&"" Q1"",IF(MONTH(RC[-1])<10,YEAR(RC[-1])&""-""&RIGHT(YEAR(RC[-1]),2)+1&"" Q2"",IF(MONTH(RC[-1])<13,YEAR(RC[-1])&""-""&RIGHT(YEAR(RC[-1]),2)+1&"" Q3""))))"
Next rng
```

Comment: Are you sure, you want to overwrite every range the user selects automatically? Please provide the formulas within the `IF`-Formula - it might make a difference ... For doing the insert automatically you have to use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange`-event and then use `Target` for applying the formula.

Comment: `ActiveCell` is always a single cell. You're likely looking for `Selection`. Also, it'd probably be easier to work with R1C1-style formulas here.

Comment: @Ike sure, this is the formula I was going to replace it with 
"=IF(MONTH(RC[-1])<4,YEAR(RC[-1])-1&""-""&RIGHT(YEAR(RC[-1]),2)&"" Q4"",IF(MONTH(RC[-1])<7,YEAR(RC[-1])&""-""&RIGHT(YEAR(RC[-1]),2)+1&"" Q1"",IF(MONTH(RC[-1])<10,YEAR(RC[-1])&""-""&RIGHT(YEAR(RC[-1]),2)+1&"" Q2"",IF(MONTH(RC[-1])<13,YEAR(RC[-1])&""-""&RIGHT(YEAR(RC[-1]),2)+1&"" Q3""))))"

Basically I'm trying use a macro to populate the financial Year and Quarter based on the date in the left hand cell

Comment: You want to have B1:B5 all have VALID if A1 = "Jan", ... or A1 = Jan, A2 = Feb, ... or A1 = Jan, A2 = Jan, ... ? Same with H7:H20, what's the logic there? You can have something like `Dim rng As Range... Set rng = Selection` and with `.Offset(,-1)` look at the column in front of it. Depending on what you'd want, you can assign it to an array and paste all values at once like so `rng.Value = arr`

Comment: I'm using office 2016 so don't have the IFS function anymore :(

Comment: Do you want to keep it as formula or only have the value, i.e. "2023 Q1"? It can be quite simplified if it's just a value with vba.

Comment: Also, just for info, I am doing UK Financial Quarters, not Quarters for the year. SO Q1 is Apr-Jun, Q2 Jul-Sep etc. etc.

Comment: In A1:A5: are these valid dates? - as per your question the values are "Jan", etc.? Then the formula wouldn't work,.

Comment: @Notus_Panda the end result could just be text.  My previous efforts where all a formula behind the text, but plain text would be fine too.

Comment: @Ike - my apologies, I should have just put the full issue up, I thought I was making it simpler, instead I have complicated it.
  
I regularly get a list of dates in my data and need to show the financial year and quarter for those dates, so the data would all be valid dates as they are system generated.

Comment: Absolutely no idea what you're talking about.  Where does VALID come into it?  Where do quarters come into it?  You want the quarter that the month is in?  Think I've figured out you want something to happen if the cells immediately to the left have short month names in?

Comment: Maybe you should update your question - based on all our comments ...

Comment: @Ike, good idea thanks.  I have edited the original question.  I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: `=CHOOSE(ROUNDUP(MONTH(RC[-1])/3,0),4,1,2,3)` to get the quarter?

Comment: @all
Thanks for all your help guys, I have found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Worksheet_SelectionChange event and the Target-range which represents the selected cells.

Furthermore I would propose to add a separate sub doing the insertion of the formula.

This has to go into the worksheets class-module

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
addFQFormula Target
End Sub
```

This can go in a normal module:

```vb
Public Sub addFQFormula(rg As Range)
If Not IsDate(rg.Offset(, -1).Cells(1, 1)) Then
    MsgBox "No valid date in cell " & rg.Offset(, -1).Cells(1, 1).Address, vbCritical
Else
    rg.Formula2R1C1 = "= YEAR(RC[-1])+(MONTH(RC[-1])>=4) - 1 & ""-"" & YEAR(RC[-1])+(MONTH(RC[-1])>=4) & "" Q"" &   CHOOSE(MONTH(RC[-1]),4,4,4,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)"
End If
End Sub
```

(Fiscal-year logic from: https://exceljet.net/formulas/get-fiscal-year-from-date)

Like that you can call the sub from any worksheet.

I put in a check that at least the first value to the left has to be a date.

But be careful with that approach - as the whole selected range gets overwritten

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure 2016 doesn't have `LET` and newer formula.

This formula does the trick:

```
=IF(CHOOSE(ROUNDUP(MONTH(RC[-1])/3,0),4,1,2,3)=4,TEXT(EDATE(RC[-1],-12),"yyyy-") & TEXT(RC[-1],"yy"),TEXT(RC[-1],"yyyy-") & TEXT(EDATE(RC[-1],12),"yy")) & TEXT(CHOOSE(ROUNDUP(MONTH(RC[-1])/3,0),4,1,2,3)," Q0")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, its a much more elegant formula than mine. I will replace my formula with yours.  The issue I had was not actually with the formula, (It did work) it was with how to get it to populate a selection rather than 1 cell.  I did try to simplify it to help concentrate on my issue, but it seems that I didn't explain the issue very well.  again, my apologies for that.

Comment: Damn, I checked as well - [EDATE function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edate-function-3c920eb2-6e66-44e7-a1f5-753ae47ee4f5).  It said it was good for '16.  Never mind.  Looks like @Ike gave a better answer - might as well just use CHOOSE on all 12 possible months, rather than 4 quarters.   Seems tidier.   I was just going to add that you don't have to look at each cell in your selection and to use `FormulaR1C1` rather than `Value`, but Ike's covered that as well.